# Swift 5.5 AttributedString doesn't show in interface

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, ios15

Here's the Swift 5.5 way to make an attributed string:

```
let s = "Hello"
var attrib = AttributedString(s)
if let range = attrib.range(of: "ell") {
    attrib[range].foregroundColor = .red
    self.label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(attrib)
}
```

The problem is that the label doesn't show any red characters. In fact, I can print `self.label.attributedText` and I can see that the red color attribute didn't even make it into the NSAttributedString. What's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Swift thinks you're applying the SwiftUI attributes, which UIKit doesn't understand. You have to specify what *kind* of attributed string attribute this is:

```
attrib[range].uiKit.foregroundColor = .red
//            ^^^^^
```